# Qt 5: shared and static libraries

Tags: qt, shared-libraries, qt-creator, qt5, static-linking

From this [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html) it is not clear whether it is possible to build an executable that uses shared libraries once Qt (> 5.0) has been rebuilt in static mode.

I need to build both executables that use shared libraries and executables which are usable without them. Do I need to have two separate installations of Qt for that, or is it possible to use a flag to specify the desired behaviour?

Is it possible to configure QtCreator for this purpose?

Platform: Windows 7, MinGW32/GCC 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using Qt on Windows 7 in the (almost) exact configuration as you described. Only thing is that you will have to create 2 different compilation Kits for each purpose.

For static compile I have mingw32 compiler and for shared compile I have MSVC2010 32 bit SDK.

EDIT:
Yes I have a statically built version of Qt 4.8.4 (qmake) and I have a Qt 5.0.0 MSVC2010 32bit (SDK) (normally built). I have created 2 separate 'Kits' using these two versions and having different compilers as mentioned. You need to include the following line to the .pro file. It gets ignored during shared build.

```
#CONFIG += staticlib
```

Comment: In QtCreator, I cannot find anything that allows me to specify whether I want to use static or shared libraries. All I could get from the documentation is that when you build Qt, if you specify the -static parameter at configuration time, you get a static version of Qt from which you can get statically linked executables.

Comment: OK, so you confirm that to build a statically and a dynamically linked  executables, it is necessary to have two separate Qt installations. Thank you.